# Scala futures not outputting to screen despite using awaitAll?

Tags: scala

I'm using an older version of `scala 2.7.6`

the following code compiles and runs. but i do not get any output despite having used `awaitAll()`

```
import scala.actors.Futures._

def bubbles = {
    val bubbles = for (i <- 1 to 20) yield {
        future {
            Thread.sleep(100)
            println("pop " + i)
           "pop " + i
        }
    }
    awaitAll(30000, bubbles:_*) foreach println _
}

bubbles
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: How do you run your code? and what do you get?

Comment: @maks `scala code.scala`  -> no output.  the program finishes execution

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is fine, however, if you are not directly evaluating (like in a REPL or Worksheet) you need to define a main method.

The following will work:

```
import scala.actors.Futures._

object Main {

    def bubbles = {
        //Your algorithm here
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        Main.bubbles
    }
}
```